# Will the android webView be Chrome engine based since android 4.1?

Tags: android, webview, chromium, chrome-for-android

According to 2012 [google I/O talk](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/google-io-2012-android-fireside-chat/2637) (excerpt below), android webView will be chromium based since version 4.1. Is this already the case for the source code downloaded?

In addition, how should I interpret the statement that "WebView and Chrome browser will be the same"? Does that mean the chrome browser will be built upon webView just as the original android browser was.

> Q: With Chrome on Android what happens to the original Android browser
>   and WebView?
>
> A: ICS->JB upgrade will not pre-install Chrome. WebView will be
>   converted to Chromium based code. Android and Chrome engineers are
>   working together.
>
> Q: Will WebView get updated?
>
> A: WebView and Chrome browser will be the same when the OS is
>   upgraded. Every 6 weeks Chrome will be updated but WebView will not.
>   Just to be careful not to break anything.

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/google-io-2012-android-fireside-chat/2637

Answer (score 3):

pierr,
Based on what I see in the chromium source code it does not look like Chrome is built on top of WebView. I can see that a new class named ContentView is used by Chrome to function as the Chrome equivalent of "WebView".

The way I would interpret the statement you have mentioned is that Chrome & Android's WebView will share the same underlying WebKit code and potentially the interfaces that connect the Java layer functionality to C++ code. At least for the time being, Chrome is likely to use its own implementation of a webview-like class for its purposes.

Comment: Plans are that Chrome will use Blink rendering engine not WebKit.  Only Chrome on iOS will continue to use WebKit as Apple insist on using WebKit for rendering engine

Answer (score 3):

A look at the Android 4.1 sourcecode on GrepCode shows that the webview can only use one provider: the classic webview provider, which is based on the stock Android Browser.

In Android 4.2, the WebView has 2 possible providers: the classic webview provider and the chromium webview provider. However, the Chromium webview works only in non-release (debug) versions of Android, and only if you enable a special flag. The default provider for the WebView is still the classic webview based on the stock Android Browser.

For a deep dive into the Android source code that supports these assertions:
http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/jellybean-webview-html-rendering-engine/

As far as "WebView and Chrome browser will be the same when the OS is upgraded", I interpret that to mean that both the webview and Chrome will share the same rendering engine when a new version of the Android OS is released. As new Chrome app releases come out every 6 weeks, the webview will continue to use the original Chrome rendering engine that shipped with the OS, while the Chrome app will use the Chrome rendering engine in the latest 6-week update.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at code from chromium.org:
WebView is built over ChromeView. This is probably to keep WebView compatibility instead of rewriting Android web apps using ChromeView.

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.4 WebView is now based on Chromium: [Chromium WebView](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html#44-webview)